# Spark create empty delta table on s3

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm not able to create an empty delta table using create query and then getting error while running merge query.

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: s3a://bucket/table_t1 is not a Delta table.; at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaErrors$.notADeltaTableException(DeltaErrors.scala:258)`

Create query:

`Create table if not exists t1 (pkey varchar(512), name varchar(100)) USING DELTA LOCATION 's3a://bucket/table_t1'`

Comment: in what environment are you running it? Databricks, EMR, local?